# Is there a way to compute a cumulative sum in python while ensuring the same values have the same maximum sum value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a frequency column in my dataframe.

```py
frequency
1
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
5
5
5
5
```

I'd like to calculate the cumulative sum for it while ensuring that  all the same frequency values have the same maximum cumulative sum value, like so

```py
frequency cumsum
1         35
1         35
1         35
1         35
2         31
2         31
3         27
4         24
5         20
5         20
5         20
5         20
```

I can do it in google bigquery with this syntax

```sql
select 
frequency, 
sum(frequency) over (order by frequency desc) as cumsum
from `project1.dataset1.table1`
```

I've tried this in python

```py
df['cumsum'] = df['frequency'].sort_values(ascending=False).cumsum()
```

Which gives me this

```py
frequency cumsum
1          5
1          4
1          3
1          2
2         31
2         29
3         27
4         24
5         20
5         15
5         10
5          5
```

So I tried adding this syntax:

```py
df['max_cumsum'] = df['frequency'].apply(lambda x: df[df['frequency'] == x]['cumsum'].max())
```

but it runs forever. I'm clearly doing something wrong here. Please throw me a lifeline

Comment: why `cumsum` over frequency `1` is `5`? shouldn't it be `35`?

Comment: It should be yes... let me edit that... it's 2:45am in South Africa. I'm a little drowsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `map`:

```
df['cumsum'] = df['frequency'].map(df['frequency'].groupby(df['frequency']).sum()
                  .sort_index(ascending=False)
                  .cumsum() 
               )
```

Output:

```
    frequency  cumsum
0           1      35
1           1      35
2           1      35
3           1      35
4           2      31
5           2      31
6           3      27
7           4      24
8           5      20
9           5      20
10          5      20
11          5      20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
df['New'] = df.groupby('frequency')['cumsum'].transform('max')
```